# Codeignigniter Tank Auth...cookies?

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies, tankauth

I am wondering about Tank Auth for Codeigniter, does it use cookies to store login details? I have been instructed not to use cookies on a new project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Codeigniter 'sessions' are cookies, so unless you use something like http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session you will always be using cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your will need to use cookies on the on the website to know which users are which.

Are you sure the request is not to store "session" details inside the cookie? By using the Codeigniter session class, you can store all the session information inside your database, and just have a small enrypted cookie on the users computer that simply stores the session_ID.

This means users cannot edit their cookie to do things like "admin = true" and gain access to areas they should not